# How to Combine New Variants with Dark Mode (class) in Tailwind V3?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a NextJS app and Tailwind V3 and am using a simple dark mode switch component to switch between light and dark themes.

I have added my own new variant, VarOne, with the idea of basically being able to combine differnt style layouts with a light and dark theme. Here's a very basic example:

```
export default function Home() {

function handleOne() {
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
    target.classList.toggle('varOne')
}

return (
    <div className='w-screen h-screen bg-white dark:bg-black'>
        <ThemeButton size="6"/>
        <div className='font-bold text-black dark:text-white'>home</div>
        <div className='flex flex-row'>
            // THIS THE IMPORTANT CSS BELOW
            <button onClick={handleOne} className='text-black dark:text-white varOne:text-red-500 dark:varOne:text-blue-600'>variant 1</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

This all works fine until we are in dark mode. Both the ThemeButton and my ad hoc button add their classes to the documents's html tag and varOne:text-red-500 **does** get applied when we're in 'light' mode and the simple button is clicked. The problem is neither the combined dark:varOne:text-blue-600 or varOne:dark:text-blue-600 work.

This is the plugins section of my tailwind config file (this was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272627/12523378))

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant, e }) {
        addVariant('varOne', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
            modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
                return `.varOne .${e(`varOne${separator}${className}`)}` // this is CSS selector
            })
        })
    })
],
```

Can anyone show me how to get dark: to work with varOne: please?

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/0e81be62622) here though you do really need to see the DOM tree and specifically the html tag to see what's happening.